# mysql Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I have ran into a wall with trying to connect to my site now it worked fine till I added a shoutbox but I don't think it has caused it to run into a Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I have several sites running and only this one site seems to be running into this problem I have reset password and still no luck please someone help me.

**config.php**

```
$site_settings['mysql_host'] = "localhost";
$site_settings['mysql_user'] = "root";
$site_settings['mysql_pass'] = "PasswordHash";
$site_settings['mysql_db']   = "project";
```

**cms.php**

```
    function dbconn()
{
    global $site_settings;

if (!@mysql_connect($site_settings['mysql_host'], $site_settings['mysql_user'], $site_settings['mysql_pass']))
{
  switch (mysql_errno())
  {
    case 1040:
    case 2002:
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
            die("<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"5 $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]\"></head><body><table border='0' width='100%' height='100%'><tr><td><h3 align='center'>The server load is very high at the moment. Retrying, please wait...</h3></td></tr></table></body></html>");
        else
            die("Too many users. Please press the Refresh button in your browser to retry.");
    default:
        die("[" . mysql_errno() . "] dbconn: mysql_connect: " . mysql_error());
  }
}
mysql_select_db($site_settings['mysql_db'])
    or die('dbconn: mysql_select_db: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_set_charset('utf8');
}
```

screenshot - http://prntscr.com/b7nnc7

P.S I have gotten error_reporting(E_ALL); intact also.

Comment: Double check your config file on your server has been uploaded correctly. It's not using your specified username and password.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it with adding a dbconn() within login page and not having any issues anymore thanks for the help though :D